# ezyang / git-ftp on Windows

Tags: python, windows, git, git-ftp

I have been trying to install git-ftp from https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp on my windows. I know most of git-ftp need cygwin or just cant be install on windows but, since its coded in Python and you can install a Python interpreter on windows, i tough i could install it.

I installed Python 3.2, added it to my path. Then i pulled the lastest version of git-ftp and followed the install instructions which are pretty clear :

```
Requirements: [git-python 3.x] ( http://gitorious.org/git-python )  
it can be installed with `easy_install gitpython`

Usage: `python git-ftp.py`
```

Then i run 'python git-ftp.py' and i get the following error :

```
python git-ftp.py install
File "git-ftp.py", line 322
  print complaint
                ^
SynthaxError: invalid synthax
```

My question is : why dosent it work? is it a python error, git-ftp script error, windows compatibility issues?
Note : I didint installed 'easy_install gitpython', do i absolutly need it?

**Edit :**

I also tried to install *python-2.7.2.amd64-pdb* and runned the same command and i get an other error :

```
python git-ftp.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "git-ftp.py", line 48, in <module>
    from git import Tree, Blob, Repo, Git, Submodule
ImportError : No module named git
```

I Belive it is beacause the script cant find my git or something like that, I then tried to put the correct 'ftpdata' file in a .git folder and runned the script from the root folder of the .git and even tried to run it from the .git folder itself. That didint work either.

I dont know if it matters but i have a Windows 7 - 64 bit (Intel Core2 Duo CPU T9600)

My question is : how to tell the python script where's the git module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git-ftp is written Python 2, and is not, as it stands, compatible with Python 3. Install an earlier version of the interpreter.

**Edit.** You need to install the git-python library. Since the easiest way to install libraries is `easy_install`, you should set it up with the instructions here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools and then run `easy_install git-python`.

Comment: I Tried _python-2.7.2.amd64-pdb_ also but it dosent seem to work. It fails at line 42 tough (where the 3.2 failed at like 322). See my **EDIT :** for more information.

Comment: git-ftp seems to be for python 3, so I don't understand the old `print complaint` instruction

Comment: No, it uses **git-** python 3, which is a library, not Python 3, which is a language.

Comment: Is ther a way to install _git-python 3_ on windows without using easy_install or any other tool that require cygwin? I did a couple of research and i couldent find any.

Comment: Not that I know of... quite frankly, you're my first Windows users.